# Getting data from Access to Excel VBA sheets name

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I've got a problem with getting names of tables/sheets from an access database.

I guess it's because of the function *opendatabase*. When I use this method, I get a worksheet object with a file name as an output.

I don't how to get name of the table that I'm loading from this access file. The purpose of this program is to get all tables with its names from an access file to an Excel file.

```
    Sub CleanGoodVersion()

        GetDataFromETAPWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        selection_dossier = ""
        Dim NameOfSheet As String
        Dim directory As String
        directory = Range("C6").Text

        ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L500").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

        For compteur = 1 To Sheets("Feuil1").Range("C7").Value Step 1
            selection_dossier = selection_dossier & "{down},"
            SendKeys selection_dossier & "{enter}", False
            Workbooks.OpenDatabase (directory)
            DatebaseWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name '
            NameOfSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
            ' copy table from database
            'toto.Select ' it' s for check out names of files
             Workbooks(DatebaseWorkbook).Activate

            Cells(1, 1).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ....................

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks(DatebaseWorkbook).Close
            SaveChanges = True

        Next compteur

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this *can* be done with OpenDatabase, but if it can, then its probably something like this:

```
 Workbooks.OpenDatabase Filename:="yourAccessDB.mdb", _ 
 CommandText:="Select s.Name From MSySObjects As s Where s.Type=1", _ 
 CommandType:=xlCmdSql, _ 
 BackgroundQuery:=False, _ 
 ImportDataAs:=xlQuery
```

I can't test it right now, but, if this works, then it should return a workbook containing all of the table names in the Access MDB.